# Error 3 'Survey.fillmydropdownlist()': not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Thanks, i need some help, and theres error for `DBOperation dbo = new DBOperation();` which they say type or namespace cannot be found.

```
 public partial class Survey : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

     public DataTable fillmydropdownlist()
  {
     DataTable drpdt = new DataTable();
     SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection();
     try
     {

     con.ConnectionString = @"SurveyFdBk_DB";
     con.Open();
     string q = "SELECT * FROM [Survey]";
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q,con);
     SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     return drpdt;
     }
     catch { }
     finally{ con.Close(); }
  }
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    DBOperation dbo = new DBOperation();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = dbo.fillmydropdownlist();
    DataTable drpdt= new DataTable();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DropDownList1.DataSource = drpdt;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField="SurveyName";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField="SurveyID";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: Simply put a `return null` statement in your catch block to avoid the first error. As for the `DBOperation` class, I have not heard of it. Perhaps you are missing a `using` statement at the top of the file referencing the namespace?

Comment: instead of editing my post you should select "Add Comment" to add a comment to me here. If you put an @ before my alias then I will get a notification

Comment: By error handling I mean you should do something with the error. At the moment you just ignore it. If it is an expected error then you should catch the specific Exception. If it is not then I would log or display it to the user. By ignoring all errors you make it harder to track down potential issues in your code

Answer (score 0):

All the paths of execution must return something. In your method above there are 2 paths:

```
public DataTable fillmydropdownlist()
{
   try
   {
       //path 1
       return drpdt;
   }
   catch 
   {
       //path 2
       return null; //need return value here
   }
}
```

In the event of an exception being thrown you need to return some sort of value, perhaps `null`?

That being said catching all errors with no logging or handling is not an advisable practice. You should consider adding some error handling and you should dispose of your `DataAdapter` in your finally block as well.